# What is wrong with this 12-hour time regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

Got a form that inputs time in the following format: HH:MM am/pm. Hours are always zero-padded (or at least should be). Receiving this error:

**Warning:  preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ':' in (file name here)**

```
public static function timeToInt( $time )
{
    $pattern = "(?<hour>[0-9]{2}):(?<minutes>[0-9]{2}) (?<xm>[am|pm]{2})";
    $matches = [];

    if( preg_match_all( $pattern , $time , $matches ) )
    {
        $hour = $matches['hour'];
        $xm = $matches['xm'];

        if( $hour != 12 && $xm == "pm" )
        {
            $hour += 12;
        }

        if( $hour == 12 && $xm == "am" )
        {
            $hour = 0;
        }

        return ( $hour * 100 ) + $minutes;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Wrap your regexp in `/` or `#` or similar.... because you haven't specified any such "delimiter", pcre assumes that you're using the braces `(...)` as a delimiter, and that the first closing brace closes the regexp.... [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: That cleared it up, thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker, do you want to put this up as an answer to keep people from pursuing this? Otherwise, perhaps we should close the question for it being a more simple correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your regexp in `/` or `#` "delimiters" or similar.

Because you haven't specified any such "delimiter", pcre assumes that you're using the braces (...) as a delimiter, and that the first closing brace closes the regexp.

Anything after the closing delimiter is considered a `switch` that changes the behaviour if the regexp, such as `i` to make it case-insensitive, and the `:` immediately following your first closing brace isn't a valid switch, hence the error message that you're getting.

[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)